# Will I love you forever? or Will I love you for ever?

Tags: adverbs

http://youtu.be/cgNMSJTevAk?t=2m10s
This test states that the correct answer is: "Will I love you for ever?"

There are numerous songs\articles on the internet that say that "forever" is the right choice. Example: 
http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/forever

I'm inclined to thing that the author of the test is wrong. Am I right?

Comment: There is information from the OED here http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6645/for-ever-and-forever that might help you.

Comment: There is information [here](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/02/forever.html) that might help you. If you can understand it. Full of authoritative statements, but not all in total agreement. If I read the overview correctly, _forever_ and _for ever_ are interchangeable (all 2-3 senses) nowadays in the UK, with a slight preference for the solid form; in the US, it is a strong preference. _Forevermore_ seems allowable nowadays; _for evermore_ is standard; _forever more_ seems an interloper.

Answer (score 2):

In **American English**, the one-word version is the only version for the adverb meaning continually, incessantly, or eternally.

Traditionally in **British English** the one-word version means continually or persistently and the two-word means eternally. This however is not the case anymore and the American English standard mentioned above is now being used for the British version.

The two-word version, according to OED citations, is by far the oldest, first showing up around 1300 in Cursor Mundi, a Middle English poem: “This folk … that suld vs serue for euer and ai” (“This folk … that should us serve for ever and always”).

I do write "for ever" sometimes, and the only rule I could come up with was, if you can substitute "always," you should use the one-word version of forever. But two words sometimes looks better when your meaning is "for good."